# Control or input problems in games

Tags: 12.04, games, input

I have somes problems with some games in Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, both in WINE and with native games in that I can't control the characters since they always move forward or in circles.

That happens in Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas, but also in the native Linux games Psychonauts and Shank making the games unplayable (so it's not a problem with WINE, I guess).

Does anyone know what's happening?

Is there a possible fix?

Comment: Do you use a gamepad or keyboard / mouse ?

Comment: I use both. I have a x360 controller that I use in some games, like super meat boy. but it happened before I hooked the controller.

Comment: Ok. Found the source of the problem, the joystick input. Namely, the file /dev/input/js0 related to joysticks. I just renamed the file and everything went to normal. Is there a better workaround? how do I disable joystick input in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$ cat /sys/class/input/js0/device/name
```

or

```
$ jstest /dev/input/js0
```

to find out the name of the device that is causing the problem. It's probably the laptops accelerometer that you should be able to blacklist via `/etc/modprobe.d/`.

Comment: Found the source of the problem, my microsoft keyboard 600 is detected as a joystick. I guess that's a curse for using microsoft hardware in an open-source operating system :P. Still I would like to prevent this. Any ideias?

Comment: there is a description of this bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/390959

Comment: also there's the description of a quick fix here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1996702